# Looking for clustering dataset/usecase with large (10^5+) number of points, medium (256-2048) dimension, small k (10-max 100)

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I would like to test on real numerical data a clustering algorithm which works well in the following setting:

- large number of points (let's say at least 10^5, but can be way more);
- medium dimension, at least a few hundreds, up to a few thousands;
- a number of clusters k not too large (ideally ~10-20, maybe up to 100 but no more)

**Does anyone know a dataset, or a use-case for which this could be interesting?**

For now I tried to use 10 classes with 40000 pictures each from the Places2 dataset, and extracted a VLAD descriptor for each image (dimension 8192, further reduced to 1024 by PCA), but I don't really get well-separated clusters (adujsted rand index between the result of a standard kmeans and ground truth = 0.12). I guess I can have a better separation of the clusters using for instance spectral clustering, but this would reduce the dimension of the features to d=k as well, and then it would not be really interesting anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html)

Specifically, you can filter by Task: "[Clustering](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html?format=&task=clu&att=&area=&numAtt=&numIns=&type=&sort=nameUp&view=table)"

You can also filter (in the left menu-bar) by "# Attributes" (dimenions) or "# Instances" (points)

[image]

---

A potential dataset may be:

[Grammatical Facial Expressions Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Grammatical+Facial+Expressions)

- Number of Instances: 27965
- Number of Attributes: 100